# onnx runtime web run onnx, when enable gpu, cannot use dynamic input shape

Tags: javascript, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, onnx, onnxruntime

Following is my test code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>ONNX Runtime Web Example</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/onnxruntime-web/dist/ort.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>ONNX Runtime Web Example</h1>

<script>
  // Load the ONNX model
  async function loadModel() {
    // Replace 'model.onnx' with the path to your ONNX model file
    const modelPath = '../src/RealESRGAN_x4plus_anime_6B.onnx';
    const session = await ort.InferenceSession.create(modelPath, {
      executionProviders: ["webgpu", "webgl"], // use webgpu and webgl cannot use dynamic input shape, so tmp don't use them and wait onnx update
    });

    // Example input tensor with dynamic shape
    const inputTensor = new ort.Tensor('float32', new Float32Array(3 * 28 * 28), [1, 3, 28, 28]); // Example: 28x28 input shape

    // Run inference with dynamic input shape
    const output = await session.run({input: inputTensor});

    // Handle the output
    console.log('Output:', output);
  }

  // Call loadModel function to load and run the model
  loadModel();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

when enable `executionProviders: ["webgpu", "webgl"]`, it raise err

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: input tensor[0] check failed: expected shape '[,,,]' but got [1,3,28,28]
  validateInputTensorDims   
  normalizeAndValidateInputs    
  (anonymous function)  
  event 
  run   
  run   
  run   
  loadModel
```

when disable gpu(remove `executionProviders: ["webgpu", "webgl"]`), it use cpu, can run onnx work well

how to use dynamic input shape when enable gpu